Concavity of Distance-to-Boundary Function
Let $B := \bar{B}_{R}(0) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the closed ball of radius $R$. The distance-to-boundary function $d: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ gives the distance of any point $x_0$ to the boundary of $B$:
$$d(x_0) = \text{min}_{x\in \partial B} |x-x_0|.$$
I wish to show this function is concave.
To do so, I have come up with the following argument, but it is pointing to the wrong conclusion. Let $a, b \in B, \lambda \in  [0, 1].$ Since $|\cdot|$ is continuous, $B$ is compact, EVT guarantees $d(x_0)$ always exists, for any $x_0 \in B.$ As such, we can find $x_1, x_2 \in B$ such that $d(a) = |x-x_1|$ and $d(b) = |x-x_2|.$ Since $B$ is compact, $x := \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2 \in B.$ Using the Triangle Inequality,
\begin{align}
\lambda d(a) + (1-\lambda) d(b) \geq |\lambda a + (1-\lambda) b - \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2| = |\lambda a + (1-\lambda) b - x| \geq d(\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b),
\end{align}
where the latter inequality follows because $d$ is the minimum distance. However, this shows $d$ is convex, in lieu of concave? Where did the argument go wrong?

Surely the domain of $d$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$. By choosing $x_0$ to be the origin and restricting to the $x$ axis, it can be seen that $d$ is neither convex not concave.

@copper.hat Yes, $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $x_0 = (0,0)$, $R=1$, then $d((t,0)) = |1-|t||$, which is neither convex nor concave.

The error is: $\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2$  does not belong to $\partial B$.

Let $B \subset \mathbb R^n$ be convex and closed. Then
$$
d(x) := \inf_{ x_0\in \partial B } |x-x_0|
$$
is concave on $B$.
To see this, take $x_1,y_1 \in B$. By definition of $d$, the open balls
$B_{d(x_1)}(x_1)$ and $B_{d(x_2)}(x_2)$  are contained in $B$.
Let $\lambda\in(0,1)$.
Then also the open ball $B_{\lambda d(x_1) + (1-\lambda)d(x_2)}(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)(x_2))$ is contained in $B$.
This is nothing else than
$$
d( \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)(x_2) ) \ge \lambda d(x_1) + (1-\lambda)d(x_2),
$$
which is concavity.
In this argument, $\mathbb R^n$ can be replaced by any normed space.
